# How to create dynamic scenes in Scrollmagic

Tags: scrollmagic

I am building a lazy loading long scrolling page.
We want to trigger an event when the user exits each scene.  Im using a jquery.lazy and scrollmagic to do this.
When I try dynamically and normally to create a scene for each page that is loaded into the main page it seems to create the scene only on the top div instead of in each div that has a class lazy.

Here is my code I uploaded a demo:

You can see in the console for each trigger point its already indicating its past the scrollpoint instead of one in each scene when the page loads.

http://beachyogacentre.com/jquery.lazy/

thanks